# PHP shell_exec pass data to cmd "node x.js" and read in js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am trying to send data from php to js file from my server to fetch the output.

these are my files content:

helloworld.php :

```
$output = shell_exec('node helloworld.js "'.'test1'.'"');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

helloworld.js :

```
console.log ([THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO DETECT THE STRING "test1"]);
```

the command that i used is

```
php helloworld.php
```

Can anyone help me on how to send variable or data to the JS files?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX to get the data from php and give it to your JS CODE as js is client side.

Comment: actually i have no idea on how to do that.
As in future, that helloworld.php will be used in browser and will request data from the helloworld.js in the server.

Comment: $.post("PATH_URL_FILE.PHP", function (data) {  alert(data)        }); .......... whatever you echo in PATH_URL_FILE.PHP, it will be received in the data variable, you need to include jquery file before using it.